# Selection Listener for ComboBox in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

Below is the picture of my table. Columns `Unit` and `Description` have `ComboBox` editors. I have added an item listener for the `Description` column that when I select a different item, the items for `Unit` column will also be changed.

My problem is there are instances that for other rows of the table, it will have a different description. And the `Unit` column for that row will also have different items compared to the previous row.

How can I populate the `ComboBox` for Column A when `ComboBox` for Column B is changed, for that row only?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

The general answer is, you need two editors, when [`TableCellEditor#getTableCellEditorComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html#getTableCellEditorComponent(javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)) is called, you would use the `JTable` reference and the `row`/`column` properties to look up the current value of column `B` and update the values of editor you return via the method

Now, if you want to change the value of column `A` based on changes to column `B`, you would need to look at the `TableModel#setValueAt` method, which will be called when the values are changed for any cell and modify `A` based on the current value of `B`